# DirectX - minified texture quality

Tags: directx, textures

I'm struggling with texture filtering in DirectX. When I place the textured quad far from the camera the texture quality drops drasticly - especialy when dealing with text no the texture. I wish to mantain the best quality possible, no matter the perfarmance. 
Currently I use:

```
d3dDevice->CreateTexture(Width, Height, 0, D3DUSAGE_AUTOGENMIPMAP, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &gTexture, NULL);

d3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
d3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
d3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
```

But still, the minification is terrible (for exaple compared to resizes performed by image editors). What is the best way to do this? What is "the most lossless" filtering method.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What level of anistropy are you using? Setting it to 16x will help a little, but there's nothing you can do; far surfaces just take fewer pixels.

Comment: I added line
d3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0,D3DSAMP_MAXANISOTROPY,caps.MaxAnisotropy);

Comment: I added line
`cd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0,D3DSAMP_MAXANISOTROPY,caps.MaxAnisotropy);`
but it didn't help. I'm aware that some loss can't be avoided. But still I'm sure that better minification algorithms exist. I guess they aren't implemented in DirectX because of their performance ;/

Comment: DirectX isn't the implementation source in this case, this type of thing happens on the hardware itself (and the hardware typically doesn't have anything better than anistropic). There's a slim chance that vendor-specific modes exist, you could try looking it up in the papers on your target chips, but there's not much else to try.

Comment: One possible alternative, although far more involved, is to pregenerate LoD (which is essentially what you want). It's possible to bake mipmaps into a texture and use those, and baking allows the artist to tweak them ahead of time. It also allows you to load the texture, run a software algorithm, then feed the finished texture onto the GPU. You could use that to create your own mipmaps with a higher-quality algorithm when the texture loads.

Comment: Try setting all three filters to D3DTEXF_LINEAR.